# Shul and the Divine Presence

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, speech-talking

Someone told me that when people are talking during *davening* it causes the *Divine Presence* to leave or depart from a *shul*. Is there a *halachic* source for this?

Comment: Who and what were they talking about? Sounds more like they were polemicizing.

Comment: They were talking during tefillah.

Comment: They told you this during tefillah and caused the Shekhina to leave, or they told you during tefillah that another talker had already caused the Shekhina to leave, or they told you after tefillah that a talker had caused the Shekhina to leave earlier than it should have?

Comment: I jest, but maintaining kavannah and keeping people in the spirit of davaning is a tricky matter, and some old guys yapping it up does make it _feel_ like the Shekhina has departed. Does it actually?  How could any of us humans know for sure?

Answer (score 2):

I saw at [The Yeshiva World](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/talking-during-davening) a post that included the words:

> One who speaks during Chazoras Hashatz causes the Shechinah to leave Klal Yisroel, and it is as if he has sinned with Avodah Zorah.
>   Drush Chasam Sofer vol2pg309b

but I didn't see it [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21254&hilite=d22938a2-23a4-470a-bec1-a40a8349c043&st=%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%AA&pgnum=245) on a quick check.

Comment: Is there anything mentioned that if one speaks during Chazoras Hashatz in his shul the Shechinah leaves from that shul?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah The quote above is all I found.